# Error with arithmetic calculation

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to calculate 2 retrieved values from `NSMutableArray` but there was error during runtime pointing to the way the arithmetic calculation was done.

The code that inserts the value:

```
NSString *lastEx = @"None";
int lastScore = 0;
int tries = 0;
int total_score = 0;
int avg = 0;
int credit = 100;

[data addObject:lastEx];
[data addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:lastScore]];
[data addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tries]];
[data addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:total_score]];
[data addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:avg]];
[data addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:credit]];
```

Code to retrieve:

```
NSMutableArray *savedStock = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

previousExercise.text = [savedStock objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *lastScoring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[savedStock objectAtIndex:1] intValue]];
previousScore.text = lastScoring;

NSString *totalTries = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[savedStock objectAtIndex:2] intValue]];
attempts.text = totalTries;

NSString *average = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[savedStock objectAtIndex:4] intValue]];
avgScore.text = average;

int totalScore = [[savedStock objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
int numberOfTries = [[savedStock objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
int avg;

avg = ((totalScore / numberOfTries) * 100);

NSString *rem_credit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[savedStock objectAtIndex:5] intValue]];
credits.text = rem_credit;
```

Error is the calculation of  => `avg = ((totalScore / numberOfTries) * 100);`

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 4):

`tries` is 0, so `int numberOfTries = [[savedStock objectAtIndex:2] intValue];` assigns 0 to `numberOfTries` as well, and integer division by 0 causes arithmetic error.

Consider:

```
avg = (numberOfTries == 0) ? 0 : ((totalScore / numberOfTries) * 100);
```